# Same instance of pending intent is fired again and again, despite changing the extras manually

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to do a task multiple times, and task is to broadcast an intent which will be intercepted by a different app. Lets say from App **Sender** to **Receiver**. 
Receiving the intent in Receiver app is working fine, I have tested and guaranteed:

How I am doing this is, 
I created a broadcast receiver in Sender app, with action SENDER_ACTION.
I create an intent with this action, set an extra with key `frequency` and value `4`.
Get a PendingIntent from this and set an alarm of 10 sec, and fires this intent.

Idea is that sender app, will receive this intent, will fire the required intent to RECEIVER app, and then decreases the **frequency** value by 1, set it again to the intent, creates a pending intent and alarm and fires again.

So, ideally this counter of frequency should reach to 0 and process should terminate.

I can see that while setting the decreased value of **frequency**, it is happening (in logs), but when I receive its the same unchanged value.

I suspect that pending intent instance is kept on fired again and again.
Can some body please help me why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess -- which I do, since you provided no source code -- it is because you have not passed the right flags into `getBroadcast()` (or whatever factory method that you are using on `PendingIntent` to obtain the `PendingIntent` instance). Please bear in mind that Android caches `PendingIntent` objects and will reuse them, with their internal `Intent` extras unmodified, by default. Consider passing [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) as the last parameter to `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, every time I create a new Intent object, put new value to its extra, then I call `getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);`

Comment: as flags I am not providing anything

Comment: ok, so you are saying, that if action of my intent is same every time, android is gonna cache the same pending intent? coz the only thing remains same is the action of intent object I am creating??

Comment: @akkilis: "that if action of my intent is same every time, android is gonna cache the same pending intent?" -- you get back the same `PendingIntent` as a previous request when you pass in an equivalent `Intent` to `getBroadcast()`. By "equivalent" I mean that the action, categories, `Uri`, and MIME type are the same. Changes only to extras do not count. If you replace your second `0` with `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, I believe that it will fix your problem.

Comment: I am gonna try to use this flag value, you told, but if you can revert to what I asked in comments, will be helpful to me and others also. Thanks again. Hope this removes my problem.

Comment: @akkilis: "if you can revert to what I asked in comments" -- I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: whoa so deep, so deep, and I am still floating just on the surface. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks for such a quick reply. Was debugging this from hours.